# How to fix GRUB? I do not have Linux installed on the computer, why is GRUB even there?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, grubrescue

I have dual system on my MacBook the thing is, I have 2 OS Windows 10 and Mac OS, I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 in a hard drive not to work directly by the live version of the Ubuntu OS, because I wanted to install software and such without losing the changes (I'm not sure if you can do that on the live version).

the thing is installing Ubuntu in the hard drive, has also installed grub, I can enter Mac Os with no problem and no grub, but when I try to enter Windows, I get grub and a problem on it:

It displays the text:

```
minimal bash-like line editing is supported
```

I tried to follow the steps listed in here:

- https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/

But I fail on a step, writing the command:

```bsh
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --bootloader-id=ubuntu  --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/mnt/boot/efi
```

That gives me:

```
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh no existe. Por favor, especifique --target o --directory.
```

I've also tried using "Boot-Repair": https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

I followed the steps but I get the same GRUB screen.

I can enter Mac OS without problem, but I cannot access Windows. As whenever I choose the windows OS it takes me to the GRUB screen...

I'm a little lost here, please help.